# My checkedlistbox in C# shows the type of the object it is to display, but not the name of it

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I'm having an issue displaying an object in a checked list box in C#. I can add object fine, but when the object is displayed to the user, to the program outputs the checkbox selection as Salesform.order instead of invoking the tostring method in the order class like I want. This results in multiple orders displaying as the same thing: "Salesform.order".

```
orderCheckList.Items.Add(orderUp);
```

(here, orderUp is an order with fields such as name of customer and so on)

Can anyone help? I know there is a simple solution that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `DisplayMember` of the `CheckedListBox` to the property you want displayed. For instance:

```
orderCheckList.DisplayMember = "Title";
// Now orderUp.Title will be displayed
```

(Overriding `ToString()` will work as well, as suggested by Ragepotato, but using `DisplayMember` is more flexible as it means you can use the same datatype in various different contexts.)

Sample code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Form f = new Form
        {
            Controls =
            {
                new CheckedListBox
                {
                    Items = 
                    {
                        new { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Skeet" },
                        new { FirstName = "Holly", LastName = "Skeet" }
                    },
                    DisplayMember = "FirstName"
                }
            }
        };
        Application.Run(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But how could I get access to "LastName"?  Type is anonymous so I can't cast it.

Comment: @Paval: From where? You'd typically set `ValueMember = "LastName"` and then get at the values.

Answer (score 4):

`.ToString()` is getting called on each item you add to the list box. Override it to solve this issue.